# VBA Userform data change check

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a userform to update data in a worksheet, I have an update command button to copy the data from the 'data' worksheet to the 'archive' and replace in the 'data' worksheet (essentially the 'archive' is a log of all previous lines and the 'data' is the most recent information)

The information is changed in text boxes and combo boxes

What Im struggling with is for the 'update' cmdbutton to first check if any changes where made before copying the data, if not I want a msg box to read 'no change in data, please close form'

Here is the code for the userform so far:

```
Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()
' To write edited info of userform2 to Sheets("Data")
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ABnum As Double
Dim ABrng As Range
Dim WriteRow As Long

'error statement
On Error GoTo errHandler:
'hold in memory and stop screen flicker
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
' Make sure we're on the right sheet
With Sheets("Data")
' Get the last row used so can set up the search range
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
' Set the range to search for the AB number
    Set ABrng = .Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
' Get the AB number from what is selected on userform2
    ABnum = txtup1.Value
' Get the row of sheet for this AB number
    WriteRow = Application.Match(ABnum, ABrng, 0)
' Make this AB number the active cell
    With .Cells(WriteRow, 1)
' Write in all the editable options
    Sheets("Archive").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(, 14).Value = .Resize(, 14).Value
        .Offset(0, 4) = cboup3.Value
        .Offset(0, 5) = cboup4.Value
        .Offset(0, 6) = cboup5.Value
        .Offset(0, 7) = cboup6.Value
        .Offset(0, 8) = Date
        .Offset(0, 9) = txtrev.Value
        .Offset(0, 12) = txtup9.Value
        .Offset(0, 13) = txtup8.Value
    End With
End With
' Filter the Data
FilterMe
' Close the form
Unload Me

MsgBox ("Enquiry E0" + Me.txtup1.Text + " has been updated")

errHandler:
'Protect all sheets if error occurs
'Protect_All
'show error information in a messagebox
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " just occured."
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to write a function to compare the values.

```
Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()
' To write edited info of userform2 to Sheets("Data")
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ABnum As Double
    Dim ABrng As Range
    Dim WriteRow As Long

    'error statement
    On Error GoTo errHandler:
    'hold in memory and stop screen flicker
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Make sure we're on the right sheet
    With Sheets("Data")
        ' Get the last row used so can set up the search range
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ' Set the range to search for the AB number
        Set ABrng = .Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
        ' Get the AB number from what is selected on userform2
        ABnum = txtenqup.Value
        ' Get the row of sheet for this AB number
        WriteRow = Application.Match(ABnum, ABrng, 0)
        ' Make this AB number the active cell
        With .Cells(WriteRow, 1)
            'Check for changes

            If Not hasValuePairsChanges(.Offset(0, 4).Value, cboup3.Value, _
                                        .Offset(0, 5).Value, cboup4.Value, _
                                        .Offset(0, 6).Value, cboup5.Value, _
                                        .Offset(0, 7).Value, cboup6.Value, _
                                        CDate(.Offset(0, 8).Value), Date, _
                                        CDbl(.Offset(0, 9).Value), CDbl(txtrev.Value), _
                                        .Offset(0, 12).Value, txtnotes.Value, _
                                        .Offset(0, 13).Value, txtdtime.Value) Then
                MsgBox "No Change in Data", vbInformation, ""
                Exit Sub
            End If

            ' Write in all the editable options
            Sheets("Archive").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(, 14).Value = .Resize(, 14).Value
            .Offset(0, 4) = cboup3.Value
            .Offset(0, 5) = cboup4.Value
            .Offset(0, 6) = cboup5.Value
            .Offset(0, 7) = cboup6.Value
            .Offset(0, 8) = Date
            .Offset(0, 9) = txtrev.Value
            .Offset(0, 12) = txtnotes.Value
            .Offset(0, 13) = txtdtime.Value
        End With
    End With
    ' Filter the Data
    FilterMe
    ' Close the form
    Unload Me

    MsgBox ("Enquiry E0" + Me.txtenqup.Text + " has been updated")
```

errHandler:
        'Protect all sheets if error occurs
        'Protect_All
        'show error information in a messagebox
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " just occured."
        End If

```
End Sub

Function hasValuePairsChanges(ParamArray Args() As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim n As Long

    For n = 0 To UBound(Args) Step 2
        If Not Args(n) = Args(n + 1) Then
            hasValuePairsChanges = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this, Ive had error 13 occur when i press the update? even if i change the data

Comment: @JamesHurst I made a couple of adjustments. Passing the cell values and casting `.Offset(0, 8).Value` to a date `CDate(.Offset(0, 8).Value)`.

Comment: For n = 0 To UBound(args) Step 2

Comment: @JamesHurst I updated my code.  There was an error in `hasValuePairsChanges()`.

Comment: The error has gone, but if there is no change the update will still occur, can i send you the file?

Comment: @JamesHurst `txtrev.Value` needed to be cast into a numeric data type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183729/discussion-between-james-hurst-and-tinman).

Comment: I had an error in my code where the    Me.txtnotes.Value = frmenqnew.lstenq.Column(12, i)
Me.txtdtime.Value = frmenqnew.lstenq.Column(13, i) were labelled incorrectly and did not populate the update userform textboxes. After fixing it the issue you resolved has started again?

Comment: @JamesHurst I'm not sure why that would happen.

Comment: Would you like me to send the latest version?